# Connection to SQL Server failed. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting this error while trying to connect to sql server. Now this never happened before and it's really annoying.

I found out in my sql configuration manager that SQL server service has stopped for some reason.

When I try to start it again it gives me error that says: "The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion".

I found some solution for this but none of them works for me. I checked if VIA protocol is enabled, and it was disabled.

I checked

- if my server allows remote connections and it does.
- if port 1433 is used by some other service, but still it was not used by any other services.

Those are solutions that I found and tried to solve this problem with them, but no success.

Is there any other reason why is this error happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried connecting using the full SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME string? For example, if your server is named SQLHOST and the name of the instance is "SQLSERVER", try to connect to it as: SQLHOST\SQLSERVER

Comment: Can you check the event log for further detail of this error?

Comment: Try the solution from the below link once
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617402/the-request-failed-or-the-service-did-not-respond-in-a-timely-fashion

Comment: Duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408182/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne). If your SQL Service stop immediately after start check username & password of mssql service.

Comment: I tried all of this but still it throws the same errors.

Comment: Check firewall rules, also disable antivirus if any.

Comment: Firewall is ok. I disabled avast antivirus but still didn't solve my problem.

Comment: You can't connect because you service isn't started.  You need to troubleshoot why the service won't start.  Start with the Windows event logs.

Comment: To eliminate network issues, try `telnet servername 1433`. If you get something like "connection failed" or "connection denied", this could indicate that there's a firewall problem somewhere along the way (not neccessarily on the server itself).